# Backcrossing in Hybrid

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology

Can anyone help me in understanding how backcrossing helps hybrid to achieve pureline?

I have been looking into the references i possess but couldn't seem to find anything

Answer (score 2):

Back crossing is the process by which a hybrid organism is crossed back (*backcrossed*) into a pure organism. Let's see an example

---

*Organism 1* is heterozygous for a single gene (e.g. a hybrid), which has alleles that we can call $A$ and $a$. We can write that organism's genotype.

*Organism 1* Genotype: $Aa$  (100% chance)

Right now, there is a 0% chance that organism 1's genotype is $AA$.

**Goal:** increase probability that organism 1's genotype is $AA$

---

One way to achieve this goal is to cross *Organism 1* with another organism, let's call it *Organsm 2*, that is has a homozygous (e.g pure) genotype of $AA$.

So if *Organism 1* is crossed with *Organism 2* and produces a new *Organism 3* what is its genotype? Well, we're not sure.

*Organism 3* Genotype: $AA$  (50% chance)

*Organism 3* Genotype: $Aa$  (50% chance)

Now we do the same thing again, to get *Organism 4*

*Organism 4* Genotype: $AA$ (75% chance)

*Organism 4* Genotype: $Aa$ (25% chance).

This effect keeps compounding, until there is a very high chance that the final organism has a pure (e.g. $AA$) genotype.